# <p:commandbutton> doesn't fire any action in <p:dialog dynamic="true">

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

I have `<h:form>` inside a `<p:dialog>`. The `<p:commandButton>` doesn't fire any action when `dynamic="true"` is set in dialog. When I take out the `dynamic="true"`, then it works.

My bean is view scoped and the command button works outside the dialog. I have already verified that the form is not nested.

Here's the view:

```
<p:dialog header="Editar" widgetVar="dlgChamadoEdit" resizable="true"
        id="chamadosDlgEdicao" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="drop"
        dynamic="true" maximizable="true" minimizable="true" width="1000px"
        height="500px" appendToBody="false" >

        <h:form id="chamadoEdicao" prependId="false">

            <p:messages id="messages" />

            <h:inputHidden id="acao" value="#{Chamados.acao}" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:outputLabel value="Cliente: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.cliente}" type="name"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Cliente é requerido. " />

                <h:outputLabel value="Número: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.id}" type="name"
                    readonly="true">
                    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" minIntegerDigits="1" />
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.nome}" type="name"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Nome é requerido. " />

                <h:outputLabel value="Status:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="element select"
                    style="margin-left:20px; width:300px"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.status}" converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Chamados.keyAsList}" var="status"
                        itemLabel="#{Chamados.listaStatus[status]}" itemValue="#{status}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="Pessoa de contato: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.nomePessoaDeContatoString}"
                    type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Id da chamada: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.idChamada}" type="name"
                    readonly="true" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Número do Telefone: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.numeroTelefone}" type="name" />


                <h:outputLabel value="Prioridade: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="element select"
                    style="margin-left:20px; width:300px"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.prioridade}"
                    converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Chamados.prioridadeKeyAsList}"
                        var="prioridade"
                        itemLabel="#{Chamados.listaPrioridade[prioridade]}"
                        itemValue="#{prioridade}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="Numero de serie do fabricante: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.numeroSerieFabricante}"
                    type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Criado em: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.criadoEm}" type="name"
                    size="16" maxlength="16" readonly="true"
                    onkeypress="Mascara(this,Data);">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                        timeZone="#{initParam.timezone}" />
                </p:inputText>


                <h:outputLabel value="Numero de serie: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.numeroSerie}" type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Fechado em: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.fechadoEm}" type="name"
                    size="16" maxlength="16" readonly="true">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                        timeZone="#{initParam.timezone}" />
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel value="Item: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.item}" type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Numero do contrato: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.numeroContrato}" type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Descricao: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.descricao}" type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Data Final: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.dataFinal}" type="name"
                    size="16" maxlength="16" readonly="true">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                        timeZone="#{initParam.timezone}" />
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel value="Grupo de itens: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.nomeGrupoItemString}" type="name" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Assunto: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.chamado.assunto}" type="name"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Assunto é requerido. " />

            </h:panelGrid>

            <div class="form_description">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:outputLabel value="Origem:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="element select"
                    style="margin-left:20px; width:300px"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.origem}" converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Chamados.origensKeyAsList}" var="origem"
                        itemLabel="#{Chamados.listaOrigens[origem]}"
                        itemValue="#{origem}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="Processador:  " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Login.usuario.nome}" type="name"
                    readonly="true" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Tipo problema:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="element select"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.tipoProblema}"
                    style="margin-left:20px; width:300px"
                    converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Chamados.tiposProblemasKeyAsList}"
                        var="problema"
                        itemLabel="#{Chamados.listaTiposProblemas[problema]}"
                        itemValue="#{problema}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="Fila: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="element select"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.fila}"
                    style="margin-left:20px; width:300px">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Chamados.filasKeyAsList}" var="fila"
                        itemLabel="#{Chamados.listaFilas[fila]}" itemValue="#{fila}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>


                <h:outputLabel value="Tipo Chamado: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="element select"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.tipoChamado}"
                    style="margin-left:20px; width:300px"
                    converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Chamados.tiposchamadosKeyAsList}"
                        var="tipochamado"
                        itemLabel="#{Chamados.listaTiposChamados[tipochamado]}"
                        itemValue="#{tipochamado}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="Responsável: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{Chamados.nomeResponsavelString}" type="name" />


            </h:panelGrid>

            <div class="form_description">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <h:outputLabel value="Descrição: " style="margin-left: 100px" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Resolução: " style="margin-left: 100px" />


                <p:inputTextarea cols="32" rows="5"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.descricaoObs}"
                    style="overflow:scroll;margin-left: 100px" />



                <p:inputTextarea cols="32" rows="5"
                    value="#{Chamados.chamado.resolucao}"
                    style="overflow:scroll;margin-left: 100px" />

            </h:panelGrid>

            <div class="form_description">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <p:commandButton value="Adicionar"  
                actionListener="#{Chamados.cadastraChamado}" />

        </h:form>

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton action="#{Chamados.testButtonAction}"  imediate="true"/>
            <p:commandButton
                actionListener="#{Chamados.testButtonActionListener}" />
        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
```

Here's the bean:

```
    public String testButtonAction() {
    System.out.println("testButtonAction invoked");
    return "anotherPage.xhtml";
}

public void testButtonActionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("testButtonActionListener invoked");
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it by keeping `<p:dialog dynamic="true">`?

Comment: Resolved, i only have to put <h:form> outside p:dialog , dont know why thou.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [<p:commandbutton> action doesn't work inside <p:dialog>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958729/pcommandbutton-action-doesnt-work-inside-pdialog)

Answer (score 0):

try this p:remoteCommand

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

this is my example

```
<h:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button" onclick="irAConf()" class="art-button">
</h:commandButton>

<p:remoteCommand name="irAConf"
action="#{configuracionBean.irAConfiguracion}"/>
```