# p:commandbutton action doesn't work inside p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, commandbutton

I have a p:dialog and there is a panel inside it. The problem is "Save" button's action method is not working. It doesn't even calls the method. I can reach the method def. with ctrl+lm so there is no problem with method name.

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="createAppUserForm" prependId="false">
      ....
      <p:dialog id="newRoleDialogId"
                  header="Add New Role"
                  resizable="true"
                  draggable="true"
                  widgetVar="newRoleDetailsDialog"  
                  appendToBody="true"
                  >
            <p:panel id="newRoleDialogPanel">
                <p:panelGrid id="newRoleDialogPanelGrid" columns="2" style="width: 100%" styleClass="panelGridWithoutBorder">
                    <h:outputText value="Role Name :"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{createAppUserController.selectedRole.name}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="Role Desc :"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{createAppUserController.selectedRole.description}"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <center>
                    <p:commandButton value="Save"
                                     update="roleListDataTable newRoleDialogPanelGrid growlCreateAppUser"
                                     oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) newRoleDetailsDialog.hide()"                                     
                                     action="#{createAppUserController.saveNewRole()}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel"                                         
                                     immediate="true"
                                     onclick="newRoleDetailsDialog.hide()" />
                </center>
            </p:panel>
        </p:dialog>
       </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Comment: Where's the form? How did you intend to submit something without a form?

Comment: I think you should wrap the `<p:commandButton />` tags by `<p:form>` tag.

Comment: @BalusC I edited. I still don't get what is the problem. Do I need to add "process" attribute?

Comment: In case the appendToBody attribute is not used. Having the dialog within the form should be ok, isn't ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The dialog, when used with an `appendToBody/appendTo="@Body"` **must** have its own form.

```
<p:dialog>
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Because, when the dialog is generated into HTML output, it's by JavaScript relocated to the end of HTML `<body>` which causes it to not be sitting in any form anymore. The generated HTML DOM tree ends up to look like this (use webbrowser's dev tools to see it):

```
<body>
    ...
    <form id="createAppUserForm">
        ...
    </form>
    ...
    <div id="newRoleDialogId" class="ui-dialog ...">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

The `appendToBody="true"` plays a role in here. The end of body ensures easy and best cross browser compatibility of displaying a modal dialog by JavaScript.

The same is true by the way for a `p:overlayPanel` with an `appendTo...`

But also make sure there is, before 'moving' the `p:dialog`, there is not a nested `h:form`. So prevent

```
<h:form>
   ...

    <p:dialog>
        <h:form>
            ...
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

   ...
</h:form>
```

Since although it ends up like

```
 <body>
    ...
    <form id="createAppUserForm">
        ...
    </form>
    ...
    <div id="newRoleDialogId" class="ui-dialog ...">
        <form>
           ...
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

it is initially invalid html

#### See also:

- [How to show details of current row from p:dataTable in a p:dialog and update after save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236228/how-to-show-details-of-current-row-from-pdatatable-in-a-pdialog)
- [Creating master-detail table and dialog, how to reuse same dialog for create and edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062044/creating-master-detail-table-and-dialog-how-to-reuse-same-dialog-for-create-and)
- [How to use <h:form> in JSF page? Single form? Multiple forms? Nested forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/how-to-use-hform-in-jsf-page-single-form-multiple-forms-nested-forms)

Comment: I removed outside form and added forms inside dialog boxes but now it gives says "UI Layout Initialization Error.The center-pane element does not exist.The center-pane is a required element". I removed <center> element but it still gives same error. Any idea?

Comment: That's a different problem completely unrelated to the question being asked. Just press "Ask Question" on right top to ask a question about that. Hint: it isn't talking about `<center>` (which is by the way deprecated since HTML 4.01 in 1998, you should never use `<center>` nowadays).

Comment: the saga continues:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350850/pdialog-form-submission-doesnt-invoke-action-method

Comment: @BalusC is this still a problem with Primefaces 6 ? I have dialogs that don't have their own forms, but everything works as expected. I will update my code then

Answer (score 3):

Adding (process="@this") to commandButton worked for me.

Comment: That would have been the generic #9 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value and not related to a dialog at all (it might have been in a dialog but that would still have been a problem if you would have removed the surrounding dialog in the process of creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

try this p:remoteCommand

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

this is my example

```
<h:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button" onclick="irAConf()" class="art-button">
</h:commandButton>

<p:remoteCommand name="irAConf"
action="#{configuracionBean.irAConfiguracion}"/>
```

Comment: @don-kaotic: It's not a solution. It's a workaround. The underlying problem still exists.

Comment: @BalusC you're right, but there is no obligation to not use a workaround if there is no issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

The appendToBody="true" plays a role in here. This attribute have been removed from  in latest version. Please look for other alternative

Comment: Answer was enhanced