# Primefaces datatable update datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a problem with primefaces datatables. I have one datatable with some entries and a column with a button inside. If the button is pressed a popup is opened with another datatable. The entries in the second datatable are depending on the row in which the button is pressed.

```
<!-- first datatable -->
<h:form id="list">
<p:dataTable id="list1" var="item" value="#{bean1.itemlist}"
   rowKey="#{item.id}" selection="#{bean1.selectedItem}"
   selectionMode="single">

    <p:column headerText="ID">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
    </p:column>
    ...
    <p:column headerText="Edit Entries">
        <p:commandButton value="Edit Entries"
            actionListener="#{bean2.updateEntries(item)}" ajax="true"
            oncomplete="PF('edit_entries').show()" />

         </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<!-- Second datatable in the popup -->
<p:dialog header="Edit Entries" widgetVar="edit_entries" modal="true"
    resizable="false">
        <p:dataTable id="list2" var="entry"
            value="#{bean2.entriesList}" rowKey="#{entry.id}"
            selection="#{bean2.selectedEntry}" selectionMode="single">
            <p:column headerText="Entry Number">
                <h:outputText value="#{entry.number}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <f:facet name="footer">
             <p:commandButton value="Save" oncomplete="PF('edit_entries').hide()" />
        </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
</form>
```

Bean2

```
public void updateEntries(Item selectedItem) {
    this.entriesList = this.entriesQuery.getAllEntriesByItemID(selectedItem.getId());//db query could take some time
    System.out.println("entrieslist size: " + this.entriesList.size()); //prints the correct size
}
```

The problem is that there are no entries listed in the popup datatable although there are some in the list after the db query.

Any ideas how to fix this bug?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<!-- first datatable -->
<h:form id="list">
<p:dataTable id="list1" var="item" value="#{bean1.itemlist}"
   rowKey="#{item.id}" selection="#{bean1.selectedItem}"
   selectionMode="single">

    <p:column headerText="ID">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
    </p:column>
    ...
    <p:column headerText="Edit Entries">
        <p:commandButton value="Edit Entries" update=":dialogUpdateEntries"
            actionListener="#{bean2.updateEntries(item)}" ajax="true"
            oncomplete="PF('edit_entries').show()" />

         </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<!-- Second datatable in the popup -->
<p:dialog header="Edit Enries" id="dialogUpdateEntries" widgetVar="edit_entries" modal="true"
    resizable="false">
    <h:form id="formEntriesList">
        <p:dataTable id="list2" var="entry"
            value="#{bean2.entriesList}" rowKey="#{entry.id}"
            selection="#{bean2.selectedEntry}" selectionMode="single">
            <p:column headerText="Entry Number">
                <h:outputText value="#{entry.number}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <f:facet name="footer">
             <p:commandButton value="Save" oncomplete="PF('edit_entries').hide()" />
        </f:facet>
    </form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: You're not supposed to change the question in such way that the answers become incompatible with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're indeed not updating the data table in the dialog. JSF doesn't automatically update the view on change of the model, you have to explicitly tell the view to do so. You can use the ajax action component's `update` attribute for this. This takes a JSF client ID which can be found by rules as outlined in this related answer: [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/).

Given the markup as shown in the question, that'll be

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":list:list2" />
```

However, there's another potential problem. You're using `<p:dialog modal="true">` **inside** a form instead of giving the dialog its own form. This way the dialog may not be available in the HTML DOM tree as JavaScript (the one responsible for dealing with ajax stuff) would expect to find it. Giving the dialog its own form should fix this matter. It'll also fix the potential future problems with invoking actions from inside the dialog as handled in this related question: [<p:commandbutton> action doesn't work inside <p:dialog>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958729/).

```
<h:form id="viewForm">
    ...
    <p:commandButton ... update=":editDialog" />
    ...
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="editDialog" modal="true">
    <h:form id="editForm">
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else not visible in the information provided so far. To start, it would  be helpful if you tell (or show if you can't) the HTTP request payload and the HTTP response body contents.

Comment: I've pressed the commandButton and that's what was transfered: http://pastebin.com/BrZirR2A I hope you can find something because the variable names are different

Comment: The ajax update is working fine. It's only that `#{bean2.entriesList}` is apparently empty.

Comment: so it's a problem with the timing? because the System.out in the updateEntries() shows the correct size of the list which was queried from the db.

Comment: Nope. The timing is fine. It's apparently not the same list (anymore). Just put a debug watch point on the proprety or a debug breakpoint on the getter/setter to see if it gets changed by something else after the ajax action was invoked.

Comment: ok when calling the updateEntried() then the list has some entries and when the getter is called the list is empty again :S

Comment: Apparently the bean is reconstructed on every EL evaluation. Perhaps the managed bean scope is missing or wrong? This symptom namely matches a `@Named` without a valid scope.

Comment: I used `@Named` and the bean was also listed in the `faces-config.xml`. Now I just replaced the `@Named` with `@Managed` and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bean registration in `faces-config.xml` should not be necessary in JSF 2.x. This is a leftover from JSF 1.x. You should be able to use `@Named`, you only have to make sure that you import the right scope, e.g. `@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` and thus not `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `update="list2"` to Edit Entries command button (even `update="@widgetVar(edit_entries)"` should work).

If, because of page layout and structure, you can't target the second datatable using above suggestions, then add `styleClass="tList2"` to second table, and update it with `update="@(.tList2)"` on edit button.

Comment: with update="list2" i've got the error "Cannot find component with expression "list2"..."

Comment: And with `styleClass`?

Comment: Can you confirm that `updateEntries()` is called? If not, add `process="@this"` on edit button.

Comment: yes, because the System.out prints the correct size of the list