# Using multiple defaultCommands when the scopes overlap

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `h:form` that contains a `p:defaultCommand`, which defines its scope as that form.  However, I also have a `p:dialog`, which I want to have a different default command.  I can put another `p:defaultCommand` in the dialog, and set its scope to be the dialog, but the default command in the form takes precedence over it.  I looked at the resulting HTML, and the dialog is simply an element inside the form.  Is there a way to have these two elements use different default commands?

Answer (score 5):

There is a design problem. You're supposed to put different forms each in its own `<h:form>`. Moreover, each dialog should always have its own `<h:form>`.

That'll immediately solve this peculiar problem with different default commands in each form.

Comment: Make sure the dialog with its form is NOT nested inside the other form

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the problem.  The dialog is created inside the form.  I tried using appendToBody="true", but that seemed to have weird side effects.

Comment: Kukeltje means that you shouldn't have `<h:form>...<h:form>...</h:form>...</h:form>` (which is [illegal](http://validator.w3.org) in HTML), but `<h:form>...</h:form>...<h:form>...</h:form>`. As to `appendToBody="true"`, if the dialog doesn't have its own form, then it would indeed cause it not being inside a form anymore. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958729/pcommandbutton-action-doesnt-work-inside-pdialog/18958907#18958907

Comment: Right, I guess I should have said the dialog has its own form, and it was being generated from within another form, causing illegal nesting. I understand that part.  But in the linked answer, they have `<p:dialog><h:form>...</h:form></p:dialog>`.  Is this correct?  It sounds like you're saying I need to have the form contain the dialog.

Comment: The dialog should have its own form. I.e. put the form inside the dialog. Do not put the dialog in a form.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular issue with primefaces dialog:

My dialog was outside a form, but on runtime it still got added inside the form. I assume this had something to do with the `<ui:include>` tags I was using.

To make sure the dialog would be added outside the form I used the following on the dialog tag:

```
appendTo="@(body)"
```

This appends the dialog as a child of the body tag, making sure it is not a child of the form.